# PHP Out of memory, but only on one system

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, cakephp-2.0, localhost

I have been working for the last few months on a CakePHP application.
Most of this time I was developing on Lubuntu, using lampp package.
Everything works fine in this setting, as it does on two different remote servers I have access to.
Few days ago circumstances forced me to move with the development to a laptop device with Windows 7 as an OS.
And the application doesn't work here. **php_error_log** contained `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`.
I've switched `memory_limit` to `-1` in **php.ini**, and now it's `PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1488453632) (tried to allocate 15470592 bytes)`
This smells like an infinite loop, but the application still works correctly on other servers. And other applications, including freshly downloaded Cakephp package, work fine on this device.

I'm confused with the apparent exclusiveness of this error. I can provide additional information if you tell me what should I check.

**Update:**
-`recursive` was at `3`, but setting it to `-1` haven't changed anything. Also, in most cases we set `recursive` individually for each `find(...)` call.
-setting `debug` to `0` brings no noticeable changes.

**Update2:**
I have solved the issue, sort of. I'll Provide details in the answer.

Comment: I normally get that error if I haven't set `recursive` to -1 and used contain. Can you confirm that's not the case here?

Comment: Also try to set your debug level to 0 and see what you would get

Comment: "Out of memory" error comes when memory_limit is being not enough to execute the particular php script. Try creating a phpinfo under your domain and see whether you are make changes in the correct "loaded configuration". It will be fine if you are making the memory_limit to 128M or may be higher.

Comment: @Nunser - Thank you, that 'recursive' at '3' was a surprise - other collaborator did it. But it haven't helped in this case.

Comment: @LeoPrince - 'memory_limit' is already at '-1' - no limit.

Comment: That is good. See if you are editing the exact .ini file which you should edit. phpinfo will show you this.

Comment: 1.3Go is really a big size of memory for a php process, so it seems more like an application problem than a php settings that should allow more memory to be wasted.

Comment: @LeoPrince - Triple checked. That's the one.

Comment: @regilero - That's true. Looks like a problem with the application. But I don't understand why it only shows under this specific circumstances. Infinite loops and the like shouldn't be OS dependant.

Comment: it's quite difficult to find the problem cause without seeing the code and the configuration, the only suggestion i can is adding to the code extensive use of "echo memory_get_usage()" , you'll be able at least to find where it's leaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the source of the problem, although I only understand it partially.
The reason lies in \lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php :

```
if (ini_set($setting, $value) === false) {
throw new CakeSessionException(sprintf(
    __d('cake_dev', 'Unable to configure the session, setting %s failed.'),
    $setting
)); }
```

This line was throwing the exception over and over for setting `session.auto_start`.
It appears that the expression `0 === false` incorrectly returned `true`. I assume that because phpinfo() displays that session.autostart is off.
I could print out the value just before the block in question, but if for some unknown reason comparison really is wrong, then why would printing be correct?
I don't have the time to investigate this further. I have commented the exception for the time of development. On production server everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
To the top of the offending php page, and see if it runs.

If you still receive the error. Check the Apache error log for the line which the offending code is on to see if you are indeed stuck in a recursive loop.